# Left ideals vs right ideals

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abstract-algebra, local-rings

By default, let all algebras be complex and unital. I am concerned with the non-commutative algebras. I am wondering if the following might be true (at least for some classes of algebras, like semi-simple algebras).

Suppose $A$ is a complex, non-commutative algebra with a maximal right ideal which is not finitely generated as a right ideal. Must $A$ contain a maximal left ideal which is not finitely generated as a left ideal? Is there any relation between generation of right/left ideals in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is No.  A ring is right (left) noetherian if all of its right (left) ideals are finitely generated. You can find an example of a ring R that is right noetherian but not left noetherian in:

Tsit-Yuen Lam, A first course in noncommutative rings.